# Creating Keystore and Truststores from a .pfx file

Tags: keystore, truststore

I am setting up an application that needs HTTPS on linux, I have a .pfx, and issuing cert and a root cert, which I received from the cert admin. However I cannot get the application to work. If I create my own Keystore, then everything works. But I need the domain cert so that users don't get certificate warnings. Here is the process I'm using:

1. Convert the root and issuing:

   ```
   openssl x509 -in issuing.cer -out issuing.pem -outform PEM
   ```
2. Import both into a keystore (I found that the -alias on the second import causes an error):

   ```
   keytool -import -alias test -file issuing.pem -keypass pw -keystore keystore.jks -storepass pass

   keytool -import test -file root.pem -keypass pw -keystore keystore.jks -storepass pass
   ```
3. Export the root CA:

   ```
   keytool -export -alias test -file client.cer -keystore keystore.jks
   ```
4. Create the trust store:

   ```
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test -file client.cert -keystore truststore.jks -storepass pw -noprompt

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test -file issuing.pem -keystore truststore.jks -storepass pw -noprompt
   ```

On this last one I get an error about the alias already existing:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test -file root.pem -keystore truststore.jks -storepass pw -noprompt
```